# What does the height of bars in the two bar chats with different "position" represents?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position

I know in this command line the height of the bars represents the count of each group in this variable "color":

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

But I really wanna know what about this command line:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar(alpha=0.5, position = "identity")
```

I know the former is defaulted as position "stack" and I also know the meaning of position "identity". But I really can't figure out what the height of the bars in the later one represents?

Thanks many in advance!

Comment: the second one is the same just the bars all start at 0 instead of a cumulative sum

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Cuz the first one also starts from 0 according to the bart chart.

Comment: only one of the five cuts for each color start at 0 for the first one. the second is `geom_bar(alpha=0.5, position = "dodge")` but overlapping

Comment: OK. I got that! But why in this command line (ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill = clarity)) + geom_bar(alpha=0.5, position = "identity")), for example, I can just see 6 colors of bars of the group "Ideal" in cut. But there are 8 different groups in clarity. There should be 8 colors of bars in the group of Ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to understand it is to imagine using `position='dodge'` (which places multiple bars for different cuts, separated by color) and instead layering all the cut bars on top of each other.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar(alpha=0.5, position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar(alpha=0.5, position = "identity")
```

[image]

(Note, the colors get distorted because the 'Fair' cut is in front.)

Comment: OK. I got that! But why in this command line (ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill = clarity)) + geom_bar(alpha=0.5, position = "identity")), for example, I can just see 6 colors of bars of the group "Ideal" in cut. But there are 8 different groups in clarity. There should be 8 colors of bars in the group of Ideal.

Comment: If you notice, two of the bars are the same height, so they interfere with each other. The smallest bar gets covered up with `alpha=0.5`. If you turn it into `alpha=0.2` you can see it.

Comment: Wow yeah I got it! Finally! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you use position=stack, for each x position counts per group in the fill are.stacked on top.of each other..with position=identity on the other hand for each x position if there are multiple groups in the fill varaibles they also start at y=0 and are essentially overlaid.