# R How to make a bar on top of bar plot, not stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can make a stacked bar plot just fine.

Reprex:

```
ggplot(filter(mpg, cyl == 4 | cyl ==6)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = class, fill = factor(cyl)), alpha = .3)
```

[image]

However, I would like for the the bars to be on top of each other, so you would see the colors mix, minivan for example should stay at a count of 10.

The bars also don't have to be completely on top of each other, bud def. not completely side to side, at least half or more.

Comment: use `position` as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/60843077/2994949

Comment: Indeed, @Tjebo, this is probably a duplicate question then but when I searched bar over bar in stackoverflow none of those came up!

Comment: Don't worry! This is also what marking duplicates is for - it makes it more likely that people find an answer. Google has sometimes quite mysterious ways. In this case, I don't even remember what I used yesterday to find it. Sometimes, I think the best duplicate results come up when you are actually asking the questions - SO suggests a range of 'similar questions' and they are often pretty spot on